# How to set uniqueness at DB level for a one-to-many association?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, database-schema, grails-constraints

My problem is simple but I could not find any GORM syntax for this.

Consider the following class:

```
class Article {
  String text

  static hasMany = [tags: String]

  static constraints= {
    tags(unique: true) //NOT WORKING
  }

}
```

I want to have **one unique tag name per article** defined in my constraints but I cannot make it with the above syntax.
Clearly I need in DB schema something like:

```
create table article_tags (article_id bigint, tags_string varchar(255), unique (article_id , tags_string))
```

How can I do that?

PS: I am also stuck for setting constraints on tag minimum and maximum size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FYI, you can also use a [custom validator](http://www.grails.org/Validation) in domain classes:

```
    static constraints = {
    tags(validator: { 
        def valid = tags == tags.unique()
        if (!valid) errors.rejectValue(
            "tags", "i18n.message.code", "default message")
        return valid
    })
```

At the database level, you can [customize DDL generation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-database-object) by having the following code in *grails-app/conf/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml*:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <database-object>
        <create>
        ALTER TABLE article_tags
        ADD CONSTRAINT article_tags_unique_constraint 
        UNIQUE(article_id, tags_string);
    </create>
        <drop>
        ALTER TABLE article_tags 
        DROP CONSTRAINT article_tags_unique_constraint;
    </drop>
    </database-object>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Yes. It seems to me the best solution. Let me try and I'll update the results here

Comment: Glad it worked (just by hints), thanks for the appreciation and points, and kudos to all participants. This problem's solution, apparently, had been work in progress. - Cheers! :o)

Answer (score 2):

Initially I looked at the [`joinTable`](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html) mapping to see if it would support a `unique` key, but it won't.

The best solution I can think of is the following combination:

- Manually run the SQL statement to add the unique constraint. If you have some sort of database management tool (e.g. Liquibase), that would be the ideal place.
- Explicitly declare the association as a `Set`. This should avoid Hibernate ever running into the unique constraint, anyway.

  ```
  class Article {
      static hasMany = [tags: String]
      Set<String> tags = new HashSet<String>()
  }
  ```

An alternate solution would be to explicitly declare your child domain (`Tag`) and set up a many-to-many relationship, adding the `unique` key to the join table there using `constraints`. But that's not really a great solution, either. Here's a primitive example:

```
class Article {
    static hasMany = [articleTags: ArticleTag]
}

class Tag {
    static hasMany = [articleTags: ArticleTag]
}

class ArticleTag {
    Article article
    Tag tag
    static constraints = {
        tag(unique: article)
    }
}
```

With this, though, you have to explicitly manage the many-to-many relationship in your code. It's a bit inconvenient, but it gives you full control over the relationship as a whole. You can find out the nitty gritty [details here](http://www.grails.org/Many-to-Many+Mapping+without+Hibernate+XML) (the `Membership` class in the linked example is akin to the `ArticleTag` in mine).

Perhaps one of the gurus more familiar with GORM will chime in with a more elegant solution, but I can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I have started with the 'alternate solution' i.e. adding a Tag Domain class. But again, even if the Set of tags is unique per tag, I didn't find a way to have the uniqueness translated into the db schma like  unique(article_id , tags_id). Any idea here?

Comment: "adding the unique key to the join table there using constraints" => seems to be the solution. Do you have an example?

Comment: I see. That way it will work, but it is quite ugly just for DB constraint uniqueness. I have created the Tag domain class, but not the ArticleTag class. Maybe as yuo suggest, Liquibase is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Note that this approach does *not* consider a `unique(article_id , tags_id)` constraint. It also raises an issue with two `Article`s having the same tags. - Sorry.**

While this is not officially documented (see the relevant parts of the Grails Reference Documentation [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.2.1.2%20One-to-many) and [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#7.1%20Declaring%20Constraints)) constraints on one-to-many associations are simply ignored by GORM. This includes `unique` and `nullable` constraints, and probably any.

This can be proved by setting `dbCreate="create"` and next, by looking at the database schema definition. For your `Article` sample and the PostgreSQL database, this would be:

```
CREATE TABLE article_tags
(
  article_id bigint NOT NULL,
  tags_string character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT fkd626473e45ef9ffb FOREIGN KEY (article_id)
      REFERENCES article (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT article0_tags_article0_id_key UNIQUE (article_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

As can be seen above, there are no constraints for the `tags_string` column.

In contrast to constraints on association fields, constraints on "normal" instance fields of domain classes do work as expected.

Thus, we'll want to have some kind of `Tag`, or `TagHolder`, domain class, and we'd need to find a pattern that still provides the `Article` with a *clean public API*.

First, we're introducing the `TagHolder` domain class:

```
class TagHolder {
    String tag

    static constraints = {
        tag(unique:true, nullable:false, 
            blank:false, size:2..255)
    }
}
```

and associate it with the `Article` class:

```
class Article {
    String text

    static hasMany = [tagHolders: TagHolder]
}
```

In order to provide a clean public API, we're adding the methods `String[] getTags()`, `void setTags(String[]`. That way, we can also call the constructor with named parameters, like, `new Article(text: "text", tags: ["foo", "bar"])`. We're also adding the `addToTags(String)` closure, which mimicks GORM's corresponding "magic method".

```
class Article {
    String text

    static hasMany = [tagHolders: TagHolder]

    String[] getTags() { 
        tagHolders*.tag
    }

    void setTags(String[] tags) {
        tagHolders = tags.collect { new TagHolder(tag: it) }
    } 

    {
        this.metaClass.addToTags = { String tag ->
            tagHolders = tagHolders ?: []
            tagHolders << new TagHolder(tag: tag)
        }
    }
}
```

It's a workaround, but there's not too much coding involved.
A drawback, we're getting an additional JOIN table. Nevertheless, this pattern allows for applying any available constraints.

Finally, a test case could look like this one:

```
class ArticleTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    void testUniqueTags_ShouldFail() {
        shouldFail { 
            def tags = ["foo", "foo"] // tags not unique
            def article = new Article(text: "text", tags: tags)
            assert ! article.validate()
            article.save()
        }
    }

    void testUniqueTags() {     
        def tags = ["foo", "bar"]
        def article = new Article(text: "text", tags: tags)
        assert article.validate()
        article.save()
        assert article.tags.size() == 2
        assert TagHolder.list().size() == 2
    }

    void testTagSize_ShouldFail() {
        shouldFail { 
            def tags = ["f", "b"] // tags too small
            def article = new Article(text: "text", tags: tags)
            assert ! article.validate()
            article.save()
        }
    }

    void testTagSize() {        
        def tags = ["foo", "bar"]
        def article = new Article(text: "text", tags: tags)
        assert article.validate()
        article.save()
        assert article.tags.size() == 2
        assert TagHolder.list().size() == 2
    }

    void testAddTo() {
        def article = new Article(text: "text")
        article.addToTags("foo")
        article.addToTags("bar")
        assert article.validate()
        article.save()
        assert article.tags.size() == 2
        assert TagHolder.list().size() == 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Robbert, very nice answer. This is exactly what I have done. But unfortunately, as specified in your EDIT comment, I don't have a way to get unique(article_id , tags_id) constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://johnrellis.blogspot.com/2009/09/grails-constraints-across-relationships.html

Comment: Almost !! But not possible, because a Tag can have many parents! So here we have a kind of many-to-many association and we cannot define a unique constraint on article. The only way I see is to create an ArtcileTag class as suggested by Rob

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to do this is to write a custom constraint and do a database check for the duplication. I don't think there is a built-in way to use a GORM constraint to accomplish this.